# Test my post api method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an api project, with a post method that looks like this:

```
[Route("api/PostReviewedStudyData")]
[HttpPost]
public bool PostReviewedStudyData(string jsonObject)
{
    //some stuff
    return true;
}
```

I can't seem to be able to test it I've written a test method like this:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:60604/api/PostReviewedStudyData");

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = "Some json parsed object";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

I get 404 error. Is my Api method not written well, or is my test method does?

Comment: `http://localhost:60604/api/Method` should be `http://localhost:60604/api/PostMethod`

Comment: It is, I copied it wrong from my code. Thank you.

Comment: A really easy way to test routes is to use a web proxy like Fiddler!

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things :

```
HttpWebRequest httpWReq =HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:60604/api/PostMethod");

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string postData = "=Some json parsed object";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
```

Also change the siganture :

```
public bool PostReviewedStudyData([FromBody] string jsonObject)
```

Comment: This way the parameter jsonObject arrives as null.

Comment: The code I posted is working, I run it myself as a test. if you have another question , please update the new codein your question as an edit

Comment: Royi, I get null as the parameter when I use your code exactly and after checking that the the Json string I send is not empty.

Comment: @tal if you send json then why you set `httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` ? it should be `application/json`

Comment: Becuase I am not a web developer, and I know very little about it (: .Still null.